# What does 週一 mean?

Tags: translation, numbers

Trying to understand this tweet:

日曜日は掃除の日。新しく買った掃除機が良すぎる！忙しいと週一とかになりがちな掃除機がけも、これでマメにやれそう♪( ´▽｀)ルンバと迷ったけどこっちにしてよかった！やっぱり掃除は自分でしたいしね。

I understood everything up to 週一. What does that sentence say?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

週一 is a shorthand for 週一回, which means "once per week".

Comment: So what does 週一とかになりがちな掃除機がけも say?

Comment: @languagehacker Often I can only use the vacuum cleaner once a week when I'm busy (the house would get very dirty when I do it)